# Pentaho Spoon "Dynamic SQL row" step configure "Template SQL (to retrieve Meta data)" using previous step fields

Tags: sql, pentaho-spoon

I have table name, field1 and field2 into an Excel.
I need o read those data and make "Select field1, field2 from table".
I have created my sqlSelect into JavaScript step like this:
[image]

I do not know field names or table names (those information is into the Excel file).
I need to run this select and thorught the result into another table.

I am trying "Dynamic SQL row" step, but I can not get Template SQL data since I do not know fields or table name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Table Input step with arguments, where you pass the arguments from a previous step, but you have to pass them in order, so each "?" is a row in your previous step:
[image: Using arguments example]
This is my Data grid:
[image: Data grid definition]

Or in case you need something more elaborated, read about Metadata Injection (you have a simple example in the data-integration/samples folder of your PDI installation).

Comment: To simplify I have donde "Select * from ?" or Select * from ${tableName}". i get error since pentaho does not identify tableName. The error is ·"Error close to FROM "Select * FROM" since tableName is empty. I am ensure that there is a tablename from proevious steps

Comment: There must be something else going on and your variable isn't passed, because I use that in a couple of transformations and it's working

Comment: Yes, the varaible must be setted on previous transformations. Thank you